# WMI: How to distinguish between an internal "local disk" HDD and an external "local disk" HDD

Tags: delphi, wmi

**Background**
I've been using Win32_DiskDrive to find flash memory (usb pens, SD cards, etc.), but after some tests on other computers I noticed that they weren't always discovered. So I am using Win32_LogicalDisk and since it has DriveType I don't have to associate with two classes (e.g. partition) to find first the drives then their drive letters.

The problem is that external harddrives are detected as DriveType 3 (Local Disk) in LogicalDisk and doesn't have 7 (Supports Removable Media) in Capabilities in DiskDrive. So I can't tell the difference between an internal and external drive.

**Question**
How do I tell the difference between an internal and an external harddrive using LogicalDisk (or DiskDrive if you really have to) or something third.

**Alright. The question has been answered!**
Here's the code, if anyone is interested.

```
program GetWMI_USBConnectedInfo;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  Windows,
  Classes,
  ActiveX,
  Variants,
  SysUtils,
  WbemScripting_TLB, // Using the .pas supplied by the wrapper as it seems to be the XP version of 1.2
  magwmi,
  magsubs1;

function CheckType(Str: string): boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
  Str2: string;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 1 to Length(Str) - 1 do if Str[I] = '\' then begin
    Str2 := Copy(Str, 1, I-1);
    Str2 := LowerCase(Str2);
    if (Str2 = 'usbstor') or (Str2 = 'flashmedia') then
      Result := True;
    Break;
  end;
end;

procedure  GetUSBDiskDriveInfo;
var
  I, II, III:  Integer;
  Start, Stop, Freq: Int64;
  instances, instances2, instances3: integer ;
  WmiResults, WmiResults2, WmiResults3: T2DimStrArray ;
  errstr: string ;
begin
  QueryPerformanceFrequency(Freq);
  QueryPerformanceCounter(Start);
  try
    MagWmiGetInfoEx('.', 'root\CIMV2', '', '', 'SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive', WmiResults, instances, errstr);
    for I := 1 to instances do begin
      MagWmiGetInfoEx('.', 'root\CIMV2', '', '', 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID=''' + WmiResults[I, 12] + '''} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition', WmiResults2, instances2, errstr);
      for II := 1 to instances2 do begin
        MagWmiGetInfoEx('.', 'root\CIMV2', '', '', 'ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID=''' + WmiResults2[II, 11] + '''} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition', WmiResults3, instances3, errstr);
        for III := 1 to instances3 do begin
          if CheckType(WmiResults[I, 32]) or (Pos('7', WmiResults[I, 3])>0) then begin
            Write(WmiResults3[III, 4]);
            Write(WmiResults3[III, 39]);
            Writeln;
          end;
        end;
        WmiResults3 := nil;
      end;
      WmiResults2 := nil;
    end;
    WmiResults := nil;
  except
    Writeln;
    Writeln('error: '+errstr);
  end;
  Writeln;
  QueryPerformanceCounter(Stop);
  if (Freq > 0) then
    Writeln('It took ' + FormatFloat('0.#0', (Stop-Start) / Freq) + ' seconds to complete.');
end;

begin
  try
    CoInitialize(nil);
    GetUSBDiskDriveInfo;
    Readln;
    CoUninitialize;
  except
    on E:Exception do begin
      CoUninitialize;
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
      Readln;
    end;
  end;
end.
```

**One more thing!**
Call this a  dirty hack or whatever, but I commented out this part of MagWmiGetInfoEx (line 298 in magwmi) in order to make it work:

```
//        if Pos ('SELECT', Arg) = 1 then
            wmiObjectSet := wmiServices.ExecQuery (Arg, 'WQL', wbemFlagReturnImmediately, nil)
//        else
//            wmiObjectSet := wmiServices.InstancesOf (Arg, wbemFlagReturnImmediately or
//                                                             wbemQueryFlagShallow, nil)
;
```

Comment: Oh, and this code doesn't only look for external HDD's. It will also detect usb pens and flash memory cards.

Comment: My initial second question has been removed since I don't need it (DBT_DEVICEARRIVAL and DBT_DEVICEREMOVECOMPLETE does the job already).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest sticking with WMI.  There is a good [delphi wrapper](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi/magwmi.asp) available which includes full source to get you started.

A query to get you started is "SELECT * FROM WIN32_DiskDrive" which would return all of the information for all of the disk drives in your system.  the PNPDeviceID field should start with USBSTOR for any USB drives.  A good resource for what fields come back is the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(VS.85).aspx) website.  Just translate the objects into queries.

If your going to be calling this from a thread, you may need to add initialize COM (ComInitialize) before making any calls.  Before destroying your thread, call ComUnitialialize.

Answer (score 1):

You can test this package; [GLibWMI Components Library](https://sourceforge.net/projects/glibwmi/) in SourceForge. It's a wrapper for work with WMI. Include components like CDiskDriveInfo, CDiskPartitionInfo, CUSBControllerInfo,... that can help you.

Additionally all the code is included. You can evaluate it.

Regards.